# Create end date column based on the start date in pandas

Tags: pandas, date

I have a dataframe as,

```
Ref_number  Type    Start_Date
1          A         02/04/2020
2          A         03/04/2020
3          A         04/04/2020
4          B         03/04/2020
5          B         24/04/2020
6          A         10/08/2022
7          B         10/08/2021
8          A         11/09/2022
```

I want to create another column named Closed_Date, such that the closed date will be the next highest Start_Date with a different month/year than the current date. This needs to be differentiated by 'Type' column. If no other start dates are available for a particular ''Type, then the last date of the previous month should be included as the Closed_Date.
So the resulting dataframe should be,

```
 Ref_number Type    Start_Date  Closed_Date
1                A  02/04/2020  10/08/2022
2                A  03/04/2020  10/08/2022
3                A  04/04/2020  10/08/2022
4                B  03/04/2020  10/08/2021
5                B  24/04/2020  10/08/2021
6                A  10/08/2022  11/09/2022
7                B  10/08/2021  LAST DATE OF PREVIOUS MONTH
8                A  11/09/2022  LAST DATE OF PREVIOUS MONTH
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a monthly period, aggregate to get the [`max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.max.html) date per Type/period, then [`groupby.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html) and [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
df['Start_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start_Date'], dayfirst=True)

period = df['Start_Date'].dt.to_period('M')

tmp = (df
   .groupby(['Type', period])['Start_Date'].max()
   .groupby('Type').shift(-1)
   .rename('Closed_Date')
 )

out = (df.merge(tmp, left_on=['Type', period], right_index=True)
         .drop(columns='key_1')
       )

# or
# df['Closed_Date'] = df.merge(tmp, left_on=['Type', period],
#                              right_index=True)['Closed_Date']
```

Output:

```
   Ref_number Type Start_Date Closed_Date
0           1    A 2020-04-02  2022-08-10
1           2    A 2020-04-03  2022-08-10
2           3    A 2020-04-04  2022-08-10
3           4    B 2020-04-03  2021-08-10
4           5    B 2020-04-24  2021-08-10
5           6    A 2022-08-10  2022-09-11
6           7    B 2021-08-10         NaT
7           8    A 2022-09-11         NaT
```

Answer (score 1):

Try reversing the `df` and using `cummax()` to get the largest value

```
(df.assign(Closed_Date = df.iloc[::-1]
.groupby('Type')['Start_Date']
.transform(lambda x: x.cummax().shift())))
```

Output:

```
   Ref_number Type Start_Date Closed_Date
0           1    A 2020-02-04  2022-11-09
1           2    A 2020-03-04  2022-11-09
2           3    A 2020-04-04  2022-11-09
3           4    B 2020-03-04  2021-10-08
4           5    B 2020-04-24  2021-10-08
5           6    A 2022-10-08  2022-11-09
6           7    B 2021-10-08         NaT
7           8    A 2022-11-09         NaT
```

Comment: That was my original thought, but this will fail if you have more dates in October or November for A. The only way to map based on the month is to use a merge. Here it only works by chance ;)